# Carbon - get first day of month

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-4, php-carbon

I am using carbon but trying to get the first day of the month so I can run a report from the beginning of the month till the current day.

```
    $date = [
        'start' => new \Carbon\Carbon('last month'),
        'end' => new \Carbon\Carbon('today')
    ];
```

The above code will show todays date back to same date in the previous month. But I want to get from the 1st to now.

Is there an easy way to do this like I am above? Cant find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try as

```
$start = new Carbon('first day of this month');
```

[CARBON DOCS  Refer #Testing Aids](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

If you already have `Carbon` object and want to find first day of month for that object you can try as,

```php
$startDate = Carbon::now(); //returns current day
$firstDay = $startDate->firstOfMonth();
```

Comment: Bingo, knew there would be something but my head wasn't thinking simple enough.

Comment: was waiting for the timer :)

Comment: I tried correcting the typo $startDate/$startDay but stackoverflow doesn't allow edits with less than 6 characters... oh well. no drama

Answer (score 164):

You can use following function

```
$start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$end = Carbon::now();
```

Comment: Just a reminder, if you want time as `00:00:00`, this is the perfect answer. otherwise, @Narendrasingh 's answer is more friendly :)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```php
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-01')
// 2023-02-01

Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-t')
// 2023-02-28
```