# Laravel Carbon find same day of week in previous month

Tags: laravel, vue.js, php-carbon

I am trying to find the same day of week from last month if today's date is `Wednesday Oct 2nd 2019`. I need to retrieve `Wednesday Sept 4th 2019`.

I am using `Carbon` and have tried `subDays(30)` and `subMonth(1)` but that obviously doesn't return the same week day.

```php
SalesLogs::loadByDate(Carbon::now()->subMonth(1));
```

This code works as expected, however I am unable to work out how to make it find the same day of the week based on the prior month.

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614948/carbon-get-first-day-of-month) ?

Comment: What about "Tuesday 2019.10.22" ?? what you going to have for this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not super clear what you are trying to do, but I will take a shot at it. What about if you subtract a month, and then go to the next matching weekday?

```
$weekday = now()->dayOfWeek;
SalesLogs::loadByDate(now()->subMonth(1)->next($weekday));
```

> **Note:** you can take advantage of Laravel's handy `now()` [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-now), which is equal to `Carbon::now()`, but saves you from having to import Carbon.

Does that get you what you need?

Comment: Glad I could help!